# Why the nested define is not allowed in scheme

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket

Here is my code:

```
(define func1
  (define nest-func
    (lambda (x)
      (+ x x)))
  (lambda (y)
    (+ y (nest-func y))))
```

DrRacket says:

> main.rkt:160:4: define: bad syntax (multiple expressions after identifier) in: (define func1 (define nest-func (lambda (x) (+ x x))) (lambda (y) (+ y (nest-func y))))
>     #(4186 125)

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal definition must be within the `lambda`. So try this:

```
(define func1
  (lambda (y)
    (define nest-func
      (lambda (x)
        (+ x x)))
    (+ y (nest-func y))))
```

Or, did you only want to invoke the inner `lambda` once? Then use `let`:

```
(define func1
  (let ((nest-func (lambda (x)
                     (+ x x))))
    (lambda (y)
      (+ y (nest-func y)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also note the shorthand form:

```
(define (func1 y)
  (define (nest-func x)
    (+ x x))
  (+ y (nest-func y)))
```